# Unable to load webpart on workbench

Tags: sharepoint-designer, gulp

I'm a relatively new beginner to SharePoint and building web parts; I was given access to the source code for a few custom-built SharePoint web parts, and I wanted to try running gulp serve to run them locally on my machine.

My npm and node versions are listed here, as recommended by the original creators of the web parts I'm trying to run.

- npm: 6.14.15 node: v14.18.1

I first ran npm install to install all the needed node modules, then ran gulp build, gulp trust-dev-cert, and gulp serve, all on the Visual Studio Code terminal. However, after waiting for it to load, it always gives me the following screen, where the option to add a webpart never shows up.

[image]

I've only been able to successfully run one application I downloaded, and I don't know why. Any help would be really appreciated!